# How do I set input path for binaries in WIX project to MSBuild output path on TFS?

Tags: msbuild, wix, tfsbuild, wix3.5

I want MSBuild to build WIX 3.5 project containing static files and binaries from another project's output folder. While with static files it all works just fine: I just set Source attribute of File element to "..\AnotherProject\Static\StaticFile.ext", I can't reference binaries, because they aren't in "..\AnotherProject\bin\Release\" folder, they're in MSBuild output folder which I don't know how to reference.
The only way to do so is set some variable in .wixproj file in  for Release build configuration and then use it, but it seems wrong. What do I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want "bind paths". The documentation isn't great about this but you can specify BindInputPaths on the Light MSBuild Task. Any File/@Source or @SourceFile that starts with "SourceDir\" or is a relative path (doesn't start with an "X:\" or "\") will be searched in those bind paths. You can use MSBuild variables to get the BindInputPaths set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Tried $(var.Web.TargetDir) - working.